# Sharing Mono with the publish method doesn't work as expected

Tags: project-reactor

I have two service calls. The second one accepts a value that the first returns. I need to return the result of the first call only if the second succeeds. The following is my prototype implementation, however, the resulting mono is always empty. Please explain why it doesn't work and how to implement it the proper way.

```
@Test
public void testPublish() {
    callToService1().publish(
        mono -> mono.flatMap(resultOfCall1 -> callToService2(resultOfCall1))
        .then(mono)
        )
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .expectNext(1)
        .verifyComplete();
    }

Mono<String> callToService1() {
        return Mono.just("1");
}

Mono<Integer> callToService2(String value) {
      // parameter that used in a call to service2
      return Mono.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you used `publish(Function)`. Sounds like your requirement would be fulfilled by a simple direct `flatMap`:

```
callToService1()
    .flatMap(v1 -> callToService2(v1)
        .thenReturn(v1)
    );
```

if `callToService2` throws or produces an `onError`, that error will be propagated to the main sequence, terminating it.

*(edited below for requirement of emitting value from service1)*

otherwise, inside the `flatMap` the `callToService2` is completed then we ignore the result and emit the still in scope `v1` value thanks to `thenReturn` (which also propagates `onError` if callToService2 emits `onError`)

Comment: Hi @Simon Baslé. I need to return the result of the call to the service one. But the result must be `error` if the call to service two fails. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I would then `.thenReturn(v1)` after the call to service2 inside the `flatMap`, or use `map(v2 -> v1)` for a similar effect (both will be "interrupted" by an `onError` in `callToService2`)

Comment: It solves my issue. The resulting code is clear and neat. Thank you.